# Is rewriting history a necessary step to use git lfs with an existing git repo large files?

Tags: git, git-lfs

We have an existing git repo with a few large files.
We like to move them to use with git lfs and Artifactory.
We read a few questions/answers on stackoverflow on this topic.
We like to avoid rewriting git history for these files.
We saw Lars Schneider's slides using

```
git lfs track "/big/*"
```

We like to know if

- we can avoid the need to rewrite git history if we move these large files into "/big/" directory and
  delete the large files from their former paths over time as our project evolves, thereby 
  reducing the repo size.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the history implies : keeping the existing commits that directly reference the big files.

- If you are okay with keeping that, then yes, you can keep the history, and start using lfs `/big/` only after your current commit.
- If you want to remove the big files from the existing commits : you can only do so by rewriting these commits, and the existing history.